# Testing if gzip is working locally

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, wamp, compression

I've a local wamp setup and installed the deflate_module in apache.

I've also set up the following rule in .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript application/json 

</IfModule>
```

But how can I test if it's working - how can I tell if the files are being gzipped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use netcat and send an `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate`. If compressed mumbo-jumbo is returned, then your files are gzipped.

Example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yourdomain.org
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html,text/plain,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif
Accept-Language: en-us,en
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Connection: close
```

Don't forget to add two newlines at the end.

Comment: Actually - couldn't you just look "Content-Encoding : gzip" in the response headers? Using Firebug for Firefox for example.

Comment: If that works for you, very well, I prefer the netcat approach, since I do most of my work in the console and I have scripts for similar things.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also recommend using [curl (download here)](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

The command would be:
`curl --head --compressed http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.html`

That will print the headers from a webpage request. Look for the line that says: `Content-Encoding: gzip`. If it's not there, then you don't have it configured correctly.